# How do I add sd field to to the summary of a numeric vector?

Tags: r

The [`summary.default`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html) method computes min,max,mean,median,1st and 3rd quantiles.
How do I add [`sd`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/sd.html) to the table?

PS. I can define `summary.numeric`:

```
summary.numeric <- function (v) {
  s <- summary.default(v)
  s <- signif(c(s,sd(v)),3)
  names(s)[length(s)] <- "sd"
  s
}
```

this get uglier if I want to handle the `digits` argument properly, put `"sd"` before `NA's` &c. This is also *wrong* when `signif` in `summary.default` is too aggressive:

```
> v
 [1] 0.9876721 0.9902479 0.9899369 0.9882979 0.9898442 0.9956581 0.9884242
 [8] 0.9897999 0.9887597 0.9895176
> summary(v)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.      sd 
0.98800 0.98800 0.99000 0.99000 0.99000 0.99600 0.00222
```

Is this really the best one can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to extract and rewrite the relevant source code from `summary.default` rather than trying to write a wrapper around it:

```
# Borrows some code from summary.default
summary.numeric <- function (object,digits = max(3L, getOption("digits")-3L)) {

  nas <- is.na(object)
  object <- object[!nas]
  qq <- stats::quantile(object)
  qq <- signif(c(qq[1L:3L], mean(object), qq[4L:5L], sd(object)), digits)
  names(qq) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.", "sd")

  if (any(nas)) 
    c(qq, `NA's` = sum(nas))
  else qq
}
```

Example of use:

```
set.seed(1)
summary(c(NA,runif(10)))
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.      sd    NA's 
# 0.06179 0.29220 0.60100 0.55150 0.83900 0.94470 0.31570 1.00000
```